# Add a global file filter to Android Framework Source Code (AOSP)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-source

I like to edit/add some function to the Android Framework (AOSP). 
At first - is it even possible to add my own edited framework later to manufactured/custom Android platforms (like Samsung Touchwiz, HTC Sense or Cyanogenmod) without much effort? Or are there some protection mechanism (hash comparison or something like that) ?

> We also wanted to make sure there was no central point of failure,
>   where one industry player could restrict or control the innovations of
>   any other. The result is a full, production-quality consumer product
>   with source code open for **customization** and **porting**.
>   Source: [Android Source](http://source.android.com/source/index.html)

And now the specific question - can anyone give me a hint or tip where I have to start, if I like to edit the Content Provider and the access to the internal/external storage? My plan is to add a global "access" filter for Users (With global I mean a filter for all applications, which has acces to files on the system). Like the User Management in Android > 5.0 , where an user can make camera pictures, add files, install apps etc. and on user-switch they get "hidden" for other users/guests. I know that it´s working with the UNIX user system.

Do I need get deeper of the Android architecture to realize my plan? Or is it possible to put a filter in front of the Content-Providers, Data-Access Managers, etc. ?

I found some media-specific source code, but I´m not sure if there is the right place to add my code:

```
/framework/base/media/java/android/media
```

If you have any idea, hint or something else which could help - please answer/comment!

Thanks!!

Comment: "is it even possible to add my own edited framework later to manufactured/custom Android platforms" -- only on rooted devices or via  a custom ROM. "I like to edit the Content Provider and the access to the internal/external storage?" -- that has nothing to do with the AOSP framework classes, insofar as the framework does not implement a `ContentProvider`.

Comment: What I mean with the portability - if I download and edit the source Code of an Samsung S3 with Cyanogenmod 13 (I mean the Android Source Code, **not** the specific cm13 Code), which runs with Android 6.0.1, can I put the code of this Android framework for example to the source tree of an Samsung S6 which runs also with Android 6.0.1 ? 

And the other pount with the ContentProvider: But how does the UserManagement controll it? [UserManagement](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/UserManager.html)

Comment: "...can I put the code..." -- the only people who can answer that would be the CyanogenMod people. "But how does the UserManagement controll it?" -- at a far deeper level than the framework classes. The framework classes' code executes in apps' processes, which means that with sufficient work, it can be bypassed. Hence, any serious security is implemented elsewhere, in core OS processes, and has nothing to do with framework classes.

Comment: Ok thanks @CommonsWare for the information. I thought at first I can "hook in" a filter between the application and the os. For example in the function for getting images from the storage, I filter the result which the application expected (return 100 pictures, after my "custom filter" only 20 pictures will be returned), but that doesn't look for a good solution. I will read more about that point and will look for a better solution. Do you **think** it´s even possible to implement such a filter like that which I can enter/port to other android systems "only" by copying the code and rebuild it?